# React native google services allocation in APK

Tags: java, android, firebase, react-native, apk

I was wondering if anyone could help me out creating a native module for Android to read my `google-services.json` file used for Firebase, i tend to extract a certain value from the JSON object and show it to the developer. However, i am not sure where is it located in the actual APK.

I have two different `google-services.json` files. My project structure contains the following `project/android/app/src/debug/google-services.json` and `project/android/app/src/release/google-services.json`. Any help is more than welcome, i am just confused on where the files are copied in the actual APK so that i can go programmatically , read it and extract the values for the corresponding keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file is not included in your app in the way that you're imagining.  The Google services Gradle plugin parses it at build time, and injects some of its values as string resources into your app.  If you want to read those values, simply figure out which string resource you need, and access it like you would any other string resource.

The documentation for what the Google service plugin actually does at built time is [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).  You can see that it generates string resources that look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <! -- Present in all applications -->
    <string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">1:1035469437089:android:73a4fb8297b2cd4f</string>

    <! -- Present in applications with the appropriate services configured -->
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">1035469437089</string>
    <string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">337894902146-e4uksm38sne0bqrj6uvkbo4oiu4hvigl.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">UA-65557217-3</string>
    <string name="firebase_database_url" translatable="false">https://example-url.firebaseio.com</string>
    <string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">AIzbSyCILMsOuUKwN3qhtxrPq7FFemDJUAXTyZ8</string>
    <string name="google_crash_reporting_api_key" translatable="false">AIzbSyCILMsOuUKwN3qhtxrPq7FFemDJUAXTyZ8</string>
    <string name="project_id" translatable="false">mydemoapp</string>

</resources>
```